# Compiling WebGL Into a C Library

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

We currently have a shared DirectX code base that renders our UI and is used in our PC side application and via an ActiveX in web pages.

I have written some WebGL demos and they perform great, no plugin mess and get rid of ancient ActiveX!

This obviously raises the problem of having a split code base for the PC application and the Web UI.

As WebGL is based on the OpenGL ES 2.0 specification would it be possible to have a standard code base and write a interpreter so that either:
-The WebGL code can be modified to compile as OpenGL
-OpenGL can be modified to work in a web page

The khronos specifications are new to me, so this is sort of speculative as I am peforming research at the moment.

Does anyone with more knowledge of 3D graphics and a better understanding of the coding syntax help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to have a PC app to enclose a WebGL-capable browser inside (together with a simple http server) to run the same rendering technique as the web App.

This will reduce the maintenance and development costs for both platforms.

Comment: http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/ allows you to embed the Webkit layout engine inside WPF.  Seems a great way to do this.

Comment: This might actually need a separate question to answer, but it might be possible to leverage Google's WebGL-translating [ANGLE](https://code.google.com/p/angleproject) project to target native platforms, it converts WebGL calls to desktop DirectX or OpenGL calls depending on the OS Platform. It is used within Chrome and Firefox.